# How to change the header height in jQuery grid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jQuery grid, with 5 columns. My column name is too large so I defined something like this in my jQuery grid:

```
Information about <br/> customers bioData
```

In my jQuery column I am seeing "Information about" but I am not able to see "Customers BioData".

How can I set the header height?

Comment: what jquery grid plugin do you use?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are referring to jqGrid, it looks like the fix is a CSS tweak as per the following articles:

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/grid-header-height/
http://2centtech.blogspot.com/2009/12/jqgrid-header-and-cell-value-word-wrap.html

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div {
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-right:4px;
    padding-top:2px;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align:text-top;
    white-space:normal !important;
}
```

Edit: As [rd22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1515111/rd22) found out in the comments, it seems that some versions of jqGrid may have an `!important` flag on the height rule (and possibly others?).  So if you find that the above CSS does not work, that may be why.  Just change the above rules to include `height:auto !important` and you should be good to go.

Comment: In the blog it mentions, load this style after the `css` of the `jqgrid` loads, how can we ensure this? I used the above css but the column height is still fixed.

Comment: @rd22 In general, as long as you reference the CSS file that contains the override after the jqgrid CSS file, the natural cascade should take care of it.  However, my preferred method is to make sure that my CSS selectors have a higher specificity than the ones in whatever CSS I wish to override just to be sure.

Comment: I found out why the height was not getting updated. the height is specified as `important` in jqGrid CSS and hence we need to mention `height:auto !important` for the height to be `auto`.

Comment: @rd22 That must have been a recent change in jqgrid (I actually haven't used it in years).  I really despise `!important`...it needs to DIAF.

Comment: well to be honest, I never checked the `css` of JqGrid, the `!important` worked for me and I assumed the case.

Comment: @rd22 Well I'm glad you found it and commented so that others that may have the same issue will know.

Answer (score 7):

Excellent but for IE, you also need to add the below in addition to above class.

```
.ui-jqgrid table.ui-jqgrid-htable {
    height:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set both table header (th) height and div height.

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th {
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
}
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following css styles in between style tag in your jQGrid file.

```
<style>
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hdiv {height:25px;}
</style>
```